# RxJS create a list from onNext result

Tags: reactive-programming, observable, rxjs

I want to return a list of transformed elements from

```
function transformElements(list) {
  return Rx.Observable.from(list)
    .map(rxFunctions.mapFunction);
}
```

The thing is, if I subscribe to `transformElements` I will receive every transformed element in the `onNext`, but what I want is to have an entire list of transformed elements to return in another method, let's say, `getAllElements`.

What Rx operator should I use to do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It doesn't look to be "the way" of doing this kind of stuff with Rx. For transformation of spatial collections (ones that don't change in time), like Arrays, use different library. Lodash or Ramda seems to be more adequate than Rx. You can combine them with Rx, of course, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Observable#toArray()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/toarray.md) operator should do what you want. When applied to an Observable sequence, it produces a new Observable sequence that emits one item: an array containing all the elements of the source Observable sequence.